# How to update existing Org's crypto material (channel update)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

We have a fabric network setup. Let's say there are ORG1 and ORG2.
ORG1 has it's own Root CA.
ORG2 has it's own Root CA.

Now, we want to add an intermediate CA into existing ORG2(so ORG2 has Root and an intermediate CA)
Thus, we need to register this ca-chain.pem into the existing channel.

There are many tutorials how to add new Org into the channel, but I have no idea how to update/modify the existing crypto-material on the existing Org.

How can I add this new ca-chain.pem generated by ORG2's intermediate CA so that users enrolled from the ORG2's intermediate CA can be authorized to the channel?

It must be channel update, but I just don't know the exact steps..

Thanks!